# unwanted brackets when printing count computed by selectRaw - Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, brackets

```
public function booksdislikedbyUser()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Userattitude')->where('attitude', '-1')->where('creator_id', Auth::user()->id)->where('item_type',   'entitycreation')->selectRaw('count(IF(attitude = -1,0,1)) as dislikedbooks')->groupBy('entity_id');

}
```

Inside my `foreach` loop, I just put:

```
@foreach($rank_entities_by_capacity as $o)
{{$o->booksdislikedbyUser}}
```

I receive the proper value, but it is surrounded by brackets:

```
[{"dislikedbooks":1}]
```

while the desired result should be

```
1
```

If there are no records found, I see only []

I attempted these changes:

1. Removing `IF` clause

   `->selectRaw('count(IF(attitude = -1,0,1))`

This had no effect.

2. Adding extra item for `selectRaw`

   `->selectRaw(attitude, 'count(IF(attitude = -1,0,1) as dislikedbooks)`

Effect: I received this:

```
[{"attitude":1,"dislikedbooks":2}]
```

**Attempt #3:** 
I tried this

```
$o->misdeeds
```

but nothing is generated.

**Attempt #4:**

I tried this:

```
{{$o->misdeedsagainstUser or 'still not working'}}
```

and guess what... i got

```
still not working
```

as my output

---

**To do:**
How do I remove everything except for the value from the output?

**Hints:** 
I have rea dsomewhere that the problem is caused by fact, that the result is a collectoin, not an integer

Comment: Have you even looked at the last comment I wrote on your other question?

Comment: yes, but it gives no output. Still, it would not be really elegant. 
I just found a hint somewhere - the brackets are printed because the variable contains data as a collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the result of `booksdislikedbyUser` is a collection. That's the expected result of a `hasMany` relation.

You can solve this problem by adding a new attribute with an [accessor](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators) to your model.

```
public function getDislikedBooksAttribute(){
    if($attitude = $this->booksdislikedbyUser->first()){
        return $attitude->dislikedbooks;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And then do this:

```
{{ $o->disliked_books }}
```

Just make sure you eager load `booksdislikedbyUser`. That means when querying the `$rank_entities_by_capacity` variable you need to have `with('booksdislikedbyUser')` in there.

A simple example:

```
$rank_entities_by_capacity = Entity::leftJoin(...)->with('booksdislikedbyUser')->get();
```

This fetches the relationships for all entities in the result. If you don't do that, an additional query will be run for each Entity model.

Comment: it worked!! Thank you!

Still I am not far enough in my knowledge to understand what is the difference between what I have now and eager load.

Comment: I added an example. Hope it helps

Comment: The example let me understand the thing. Thank you. In docs there is no clear mention how to turn the eager loading on and off. In consequence I was using the with() randomly.
Can I ask for extra clarification? Why the underscore in the $disliked_books?

Comment: Laravel will convert `snake_case` to `StudlyCase`. However you can also use `$->dislikedBooks` whatever you prefer :)